# Is there a more efficient way to do this algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, big-o

To the best of my knowledge, this algorithm will search correctly and turn out true when it needs too. In class we are talking about Big O analysis so this assignment is to show how the recursive search is faster than an iterative search. The point is to search for a number such that A[i] = i (find an index that is the same as the number stored at the index). This algorithm versus an iterative one only varies by about 100 nanoseconds, but sometimes the iterative one is faster. I set up the vector in main using the rand() function. I run the two algorithms a million times and record the times. The question I am asking is, is this algorithm as efficient as possible or is there a better way to do it?

```
bool recursiveSearch(vector<int> &myList, int beginning, int end)
{
    int mid = (beginning + end) / 2;

    if (myList[beginning] == beginning) //check if the vector at "beginning" is
    {                                      //equal to the value of "beginning"
        return true;
    }

    else if (beginning == end) //when this is true, the recursive loop ends.
    {                          //when passed into the method: end = size - 1
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        return (recursiveSearch(myList, beginning, mid) || recursiveSearch(myList, mid + 1, end));
    }

}
```

Edit: The list is pre-ordered before being passed in and a check is done in main to make sure that beginning and the end both exist

Comment: With respect to big O analysis, the optimal way to find a value in an unsorted array is `O(n)`, irrespective of the order in which you inspect the elements: linear (iterative) or jumping (recursive) are equally good. However, the actual running time might differ quite a lot. Often you don't care about those tiny differences (time-wise, that is, maybe one is 1.5 times faster, but if the difference is 100ns, who cares?), however (you can always buy a faster machine ;-) ).

Comment: The only reason I am worrying about time difference is because my professor wants to prove it. The two algorithms differ by about seven microseconds (after putting in a reference to my vector) on my machine, which in reality doesn't matter, but its what the assignment said

Comment: @user2908474 You can't set out to "prove" stuff. You run experiments, and report what you find. Although both algorithms are O(N), theoretically, recursion has more overheads WRT iteration. On the other hand, C and C++ compilers are pretty good at optimizing recursive code into iterative one. So it may be worth looking at the assembly code produced by both approaches, at different levels of optimization.

Comment: If your professor is telling you that a recursive search of an unsorted array is algorithmically faster than an iterative one he is flat out wrong. They both have algorithmic complexity of O(n), and the iterative method is likely to be faster in practice.

Comment: make use of Flag here...

Comment: @user2908474 never say which one is faster based on the running time for 1 or 2 run because there might be background processes on CPU which would affect the run time. Nanoseconds or few microseconds is hardly any difference as it can be easily affected by load on CPU

Answer (score 1):

One possible "improvement" would be to not copy the vector in each recursion by passing a reference:

```
bool recursiveSearch(const vector<int>& myList, int beginning, int end)
```

Comment: Furthermore, using `operator[]` rather than `at()` would save a bounds check.

Comment: With the brackets and using a reference it sped up the algorithm by approximately 7 microseconds, which in this usage was enough to prove that this was a much faster algorithm. Thanks!

Comment: @user2908474 That (that it is faster than iteration) surprises me. Could there also be some needless inefficiencies in your iterative approach? Also, this must be a function of the number of elements in the vectors. It is also worth testing with many different random seeds to get a whole population or results.

Comment: My mistake, it seems like i forgot to pass by reference with the iterative one as well. Now they are an approximate 2 ns difference.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know something special about the ordering of the data, there is absolutely no advantage to performing a partitioned search like this.

Indeed, your code is actually [trying] to do a linear search, so it is actually implementing a simple for loop with the cost of a lot of stack and overhead.

Note that there is a weirdness in your code: If the first element doesn't match, you will call `recursiveSearch(myList, beginning /*=0*/, mid)`. Since we already know that element 0 doesn't match, you're going to subdivide again, but only after re-testing the element.

So given a vector of 6 elements that has no matches, you're going to call:

> recursiveSearch(myList, 0, 6);
>   -> < recursiveSearch(myList, 0, 3) || recursiveSearch(myList, 4, 6); >
>   -> < recursiveSearch(myList, 0, 1) || recursiveSearch(2, 3) > < recursiveSearch(myList, 4, 5); || recursiveSearch(myList, 5, 6); >
>   -> < recursiveSearch(myList, 0, 0) || recursiveSearch(myList, 1, 1) > < recursiveSearch(myList, 2, 2) || recursiveSearch(myList, 3, 3) > ...

In the end, you're failing on a given index because you reached the condition where begin and end were both that value, that seems an expensive way of eliminating each node, and the end-result is not a partitioned search, it a simple linear search, you just use a lot of stack-depth to get there.

So, a simpler and faster way to do this would be:

```
for (size_t i = beginning; i < end; ++i) {
    if (myList[i] != i)
        continue;
    return i;
}
```

Since we're trying to optimize here, it's worth pointing out that MSVC, GCC and Clang all assume that `if` expresses the likely case, so I'm optimizing here for the degenerate case where we have a large vector with no or late matches. In the case where we get lucky and we find a result early, then we're willing to pay the cost of a potential branch miss because we're leaving. I realize that the branch cache will soon figure this out for us, but again - optimizing ;-P

As others have pointed out, you could also benefit from not passing the vector by value (forcing a copy)

```
const std::vector<int>& myList
```

Answer (score 0):

An obvious "improvement" would be to run threads on all the remaining cores.  Simply divvy up the `vector` into `number of cores - 1` pieces and use a condition variable to signal the main thread when found.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find an element in an unsorted array such that `A[i] == i`, then the only way to do it is to go through every element until you find one.

The simplest way to do this is like so:

```
bool find_index_matching_value(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for (int i=0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (v[i] == i)
            return true;
    }
    return false; // no such element
}
```

This is `O(n)`, and you're not going to be able to do any better than that algorithmically. So we have to turn our attention to micro-optimisations.

In general, I would be quite astonished if on modern machines, your recursive solution is faster in general than the simple solution above. While the compiler will (possibly) be able to remove the extra function call overhead (effectively turning your recursive solution into an iterative one), running through the array in order (as above) allows for optimal use of the cache, whereas, for large arrays, your partitioned search will not.